# Convert eps images to b/w

Tags: graphics, color, eps

In Windows XP, I would like to convert a coloured .eps to black and white.
If, instead of converting the .eps, I could do it for the resulting .dvi
document which contains the .eps I would still be happy.

Is there an easy way to do this, perhaps along with the dvips or the eps2eps
commands?

Any other simple way would also be appreciated of course.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). As it is written, this is not well-suited to our format here. Because you have two separate questions, please ask them separately. For the second question, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem, so that people can see what you have already done and have a chance to help you.

Comment: I have removed the second part of your question for you. Once you have had a chance to construct a  [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) please feel free to ask it as a separate question.

Comment: What software created the eps file?

Comment: This I am afraid I don't know for the particular which I have in mind. I found it online and downloaded this image, already in .eps format.

Comment: Do you still have the link? If not, can you make the image available for download?

Comment: I suspect that ImageMagick can handle this: `convert -monochrome <imagename>.eps <bwimagename>.eps`.

Comment: @Ian: The link is `http://www.seeklogo.com/universitat-de-barcelona-logo-145869.html`. If it does not work, then from the seeklogo website you just look for the logo of the "Universitat de Barcelona".

@zeroth: I downloaded ImageMagick and yes, it converts it to monochrome but the quality is poor, as opposed to the very nice quality of the original. Any suggestions and/or options while converting with ImageMagick which could retain (a good part) of the initial quality?

Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [University of Barcelona logo](http://www.seeklogo.com/universitat-de-barcelona-logo-145869.html) in your link only seems to use one colour in addition to black and grey. If you open the eps file with your favourite text editor and search for 'newcmykcustomcolor', you will find the following colour definition.

```
0.91 0.43 0 0 (PANTONE 285 CVC) false newcmykcustomcolor
```

Replacing this with

```
  0 0 0 0.5 (PANTONE 285 CVC) false newcmykcustomcolor
```

will turn the coloured areas grey. You can use any number between 0 and 1 in place of 0.5. However, note that University logos are sometimes subject to usage restrictions, and you should check that you are not breaking these by using an adjusted version of the image.

[image: University logo]

Comment: Dear Ian, this may sound completely novice to you but where do I find that line in order to replace the value? :-)

Comment: @lontvag --- open the eps file with your favourite text editor and search for 'newcmykcustomcolor' to find it.

Comment: @lontvag line 982 :P Nice dissection Ian!